# Android Emulator Won't Deploy from JDeveloper

Tags: android-emulator, jdeveloper

I am attempting to install and test the new Mobile Application Framework launched by Oracle

I have:

- Installed JDeveloper and the MAF extension

MAF Installed from within JDeveloper

- Installed the Android Source Development Kit

The required SDK tools including Android Support Library, Google USB driver, Intel HAXM installer and Google Cloud Messaging.

- Manually installed Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager Driver
- Set up an Android Virtual Device Emulator:

[image]

- Configured JDeveloper to use Android SDK

[image]

- Finally i deployed to the ADV.

Here are the error messages, changed nothing in between, just ran again.

```
[03:36:18 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:36:19 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:36:19 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[03:36:19 PM] The ADB server indicates the emulator is currently offline.  The emulator may not be completely started.  Retry the deployment when the emulator has completely started.  Otherwise, manually restart the Android emulator and ADB server.  The following results were provided by ADB:
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
 (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.CheckAttachedDevicesDeployer)
```

Next

```
[03:39:42 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:39:43 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:39:43 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[03:39:43 PM] Illegal character in path at index 43: file:/C:/Users/aaron.parkes/Desktop/Working Directory/HelloWorld/deploy/MAF_for_Android_Profile/java_res/assets/jvm/lib/cvm.properties
```

Full Log, including both attempts.

```
[03:36:09 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[03:36:09 PM] Target platform is  (Android).
[03:36:09 PM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "HelloWorld" to Android using profile "MAF_for_Android_Profile".
[03:36:13 PM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:36:18 PM] Started Android Debug Bridge server.
[03:36:18 PM] Verifying a single Android emulator is online and connected to the ADB server...
[03:36:18 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:36:19 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:36:19 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[03:36:19 PM] The ADB server indicates the emulator is currently offline.  The emulator may not be completely started.  Retry the deployment when the emulator has completely started.  Otherwise, manually restart the Android emulator and ADB server.  The following results were provided by ADB:
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
 (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.CheckAttachedDevicesDeployer)
[03:37:49 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[03:37:49 PM] Target platform is  (Android).
[03:37:50 PM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "HelloWorld" to Android using profile "MAF_for_Android_Profile".
[03:37:50 PM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:37:55 PM] Started Android Debug Bridge server.
[03:37:55 PM] Verifying a single Android emulator is online and connected to the ADB server...
[03:37:56 PM] Verifying this is a MAF application...
[03:37:56 PM] Verifying existence of the .adf source directory of the MAF application...
[03:37:56 PM] Verifying Application Controller project exists...
[03:37:56 PM] Verifying application dependencies...
[03:37:56 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[03:37:56 PM] Building...
[03:37:59 PM] Deploying 3 profiles...
[03:38:00 PM] Verifying project is a MAF project...
[03:38:01 PM] Wrote Archive Module to C:\Users\aaron.parkes\Desktop\Working Directory\HelloWorld\ViewController\deploy\ViewController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar
[03:38:01 PM] Verifying project is a MAF project...
[03:38:01 PM] Wrote Archive Module to C:\Users\aaron.parkes\Desktop\Working Directory\HelloWorld\ApplicationController\deploy\ApplicationController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar
[03:38:02 PM] Starting to prepare the packaging...
[03:38:26 PM] Verifying project dependencies...
[03:38:26 PM] Validating application XML files...
[03:38:30 PM] Validating XML files in project ApplicationController...
[03:38:30 PM] Validating XML files in project ViewController...
[03:38:39 PM] Copying FARs to the MAF application...
[03:38:39 PM] Extracting Feature Archive file, "ApplicationController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar" to deployment folder, "ApplicationController".
[03:38:39 PM] Extracting Feature Archive file, "ViewController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar" to deployment folder, "ViewController".
[03:38:39 PM] Copying framework resource files...
[03:38:46 PM] Copying framework java resource files...
[03:39:08 PM] Copying common javascript files...
[03:39:41 PM] Copying application image files...
[03:39:42 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:39:43 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:39:43 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[03:39:43 PM] Illegal character in path at index 43: file:/C:/Users/aaron.parkes/Desktop/Working Directory/HelloWorld/deploy/MAF_for_Android_Profile/java_res/assets/jvm/lib/cvm.properties
```

All I'm trying to do is launch a simple HelloWorld, Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that the Android emulator is up and running.
Only then try to deploy. (It is actually faster to deploy to a real device if you have one).

As mentioned above, you should move your project so the directory path doesn't have a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be a space in your application path `Working Directory`. Refer to [Oracle MAF tips](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/10_tips_for_getting_started) , to make sure you have all the settings in place properly

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is thrown even after booting up your Android Emulator and then running the project. What you have to do is, to change the 'Run Configuration' from 'Debug' dropdown. Then goto 'Run/Debug' side menu -> 'Edit Shared Settings' button -> select 'Android Emulator' from the list -> Click 'OK' button. Here is a screenshot for your reference:

[image: Oracle MAF Android Emulator Debug Config]